# How to decrypt data when you can't get the private key in Windows?

Tags: visual-c++, ssl, encryption, https, openssl

I'm very confuse. My english is poor, but I try to say my question clearly. When browser connects to a https website which needs client certificate to authenticate the identity, the browser will send client certificate to web server. Then the web server will use the certificate to encrypt some data and send it to browser. Then broswer should have private key to decrypt that. But as I know, if I install a pfx format personal certificate, I can set can't export private key, which means you can't get the private key to use it. So how can the browser decrypt the data without private key?

Comment: If this is meant to be a description of what happens in SSL, it is incorrect. The private keys aren't used for decryption. That's done via a negotiated symmetric session key. The private keys and certificates are only used for authentication purposes.

Comment: @EJP Yes, I mean in the authertication hand shake, the client's private key of certificate should use to decrypt the server's random number data to autherticate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Non-exportable" doesn't mean "unusable". You can use CryptoAPI functions to use the private key for signing and decryption purposes.

On a side node, you can import the PFX file and set private keys as exportable, if you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think the private key should be setted unexportable to keep safe. Do you means we can use CryptoAPI to decrypt data without private key? I google some information and found something called CSP which save the private key. So if we want to decrypt data, we just call some interface support by CSP? Such as CryptDecryptMessage(...)? So that is you mean "usable"?

Comment: @lvshuchengyin You can not decrypt the data without the private key. But as the private key IS present inside Windows after import, the call to CryptoAPI function (such as CryptDecryptMessage) will use that stored private key.

Comment: "The call to CryptoAPI function (such as CryptDecryptMessage) will use that stored private key." That means we just call CryptoAPI function (such as CryptDecryptMessage), it will look for the private key automatically to decrypt data? And the windows will save the private key safely and no one can get it.